# Why is DutyCycle not respected in code? Where I am wrong?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pwm

I have a PIC12F1572 and a push button (not exist in schematic). I want to get PWM on RA4 when the button is activated. The button is connected to RA2.

I set 50% PWM (13333 from 26667.)  When the button is activated I get small PWM (under 1%). When the button is released I reach 0%. What have I done wrong?

[image: Circuit]

Link to code:
https://pastebin.com/jKPUztm0

```c
/*
 * PIC12F1572 PWM example.
 *
 * Pins:
 *                     +----+
 *                Vdd -|1  8|- Vss
 *           PWM1 RA5 -|2  7|- RA0/ICSPDAT
 *           PWM2 RA4 -|3  6|- RA1/ICSPLCK
 *           RA3/MCLR -|4  5|- RA2 PWM3
 *                     +----+
 */

#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000   // Oscillator frequency.

#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC  // INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin.
#pragma config WDTE = OFF     // Watchdog Timer disable.
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF    // Power-up Timer enbable.
#pragma config MCLRE = ON     // MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR.
#pragma config CP = OFF       // Program memory code protection disabled.
#pragma config BOREN = ON     // Brown-out Reset enabled.
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF // CLKOUT function is disabled; I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin.
#pragma config WRT = OFF      // Flash Memory Write protection off.
#pragma config STVREN = ON    // Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset.
#pragma config BORV = LO      // Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.
#pragma config LVP = OFF      // High-voltage on MCLR/VPP must be used for programming.

#define pwm_1  PORTAbits.RA5
#define pwm_2  PORTAbits.RA4
#define frana  PORTAbits.RA3
#define semnalizare PORTAbits.RA2
#define pozitie PORTAbits.RA1


#include <stdio.h>R
#include <stdlib.h>

void init_pic() {
  OSCCON = 0b01111010; // 16 Mhz oscillator.
  ANSELA = 0b00000000;// 0b-prefix pentru binar bit:0b76543210
  //bit7=RA5(0 digital input, 1= analog input) PWM_1
  //bit6=RA4(0 digital input, 1= analog input) PWM_2
  //bit5=RA3(0 digital input, 1= analog input) Frana
  //bit4=RA2(0 digital input, 1= analog input) Semnalizare
  //bit3=RA1(0 digital input, 1= analog input) Pozitie
  //bit2=RA0(0 digital input, 1= analog input)
  //bit1- nefolosit (set to 0)
  //bit0- nefolosit (set to 0)
  LATA = 0;            // Zero all port bits.
}

void init_pwm() {
  // Pin selection.
  APFCONbits.P1SEL = 1; // PWM1 on RA5.
  APFCONbits.P2SEL = 1; // PWM2 on RA4.

  // Set PWM pins to be outputs.
  TRISAbits.TRISA5 = 0;  //RA5 = PWM_1 = OUTPUT
  TRISAbits.TRISA4 = 0;  //RA4 = PWM_1 = OUTPUT
  // Set input pins.
  TRISAbits.TRISA3 = 1;  //RA3 = frana = INPUT
  TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 1;  //RA2 = semnalizare = INPUT
  TRISAbits.TRISA1 = 1;  //RA1 = pozitie = INPUT
  // Set HFINTOSC clock, no prescaler.
  PWM1CLKCON = 0b00000001;
  PWM2CLKCON = 0b00000001;

  // PWM control (standard mode).
  PWM1CON = 0b11000000;
  PWM2CON = 0b11000000;
 
  // Phase.
  PWM1PH = 0;
  PWM2PH = 0;

  // Duty cycle.
  //PWM1 =RA5  PWM2=RA4 PWM3=RA2
  PWM1DC = 13333; //= duty_cycle * (PERIOD/100);  //RA5
  PWM2DC = 24000; //RA4

  // Period.
  PWM1PR = 26667; //PERIOD
  PWM2PR = 26667;
  
  //On
  PWM1LD= 0;
  PWM2LD= 0;
}
//RA5= frana cerc mic (PWM1)
//RA4= semnalizare cerc mic (PWM2)
int main() 
{
    PWM1LD=0;
    PWM2LD=0;
    init_pic();
    init_pwm();
    while (1)  
    {
        if (semnalizare == 1)
        {
           PWM2LD = 1;        
           PWM2DC = 13333; // PWM=50%
        }
        else 
        {
            PWM2LD = 0;
            PWM2DC = 0;
        }
        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked with a PIC in a while but I am pretty sure that you should not be using *return* in your main() loop. This can cause bad behavior and prevent your code from running properly. Additionally I would advise you to make sure you can configure and run the PWM at 50% duty cycle properly before you begin incorporating buttons, if you did not already start with that.

Comment: @InBedded16 Good point. Should be a do while{}. Otherwise it runs out of code memory executing garbage.

Comment: @DKNguyen do while{} would work, personally I would set up rising/falling edge interrupts. The current code **should** work without the return, but it is wasteful. The reason I say this SkePsis is because you set the value of the PWM2LD and the PWM2DC registers every time you loop- which is every few milliseconds - and almost every write is redundant. You only need to write those registers once when the button is first pressed, and once when the button is released.

Comment: Hallo, just to clarify. I want to obtain as following: when button is pressed get 50% , when is depressed obtain 0. Running the code I obtain like 1% when button is pressed (I want 50%) and 0% when button is depressed (is OK).

Comment: @SkePsis have you verified that you are setting up the PWM correctly? If you haven't, start by just writing code that sets up the PWM at 50%, turns it on, and then enters an infinite while() loop. Verify that your code correctly outputs a 50% duty cycle. **Then** begin incorporating the button, and along the way update your question to ask for help as needed.

Comment: @SkePsis also want to clear something up - a button being *depressed* and a button being *pressed* means the same thing. A depressed button means it is being pushed down. You want 50% PWM when the button is pressed and 0% when it is released.

Comment: I tested without button and all works good,  I get 50%. Problem appear when I added button

Comment: @SkePsis -- then make the simplest program you can that displays the issue you're having with the buttons.  Lose all the PWM stuff.

Comment: As others have observed, the *while(1)* loop contains the *return()* instruction. The "}" for the loop is misplaced. But the *return(*) instruction is meaningless and problematic in embedded code, and should be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much, you all were right. Problem was return in loop. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem likely is not how the PWM is setup, the problem is a mistake in the main loop returning.

The main loop that is supposed to run forever is not an infinite loop.

The loop runs exactly only once because the return statement is inside the infinite while loop.

The code then returns to the startup library and it likely just starts executing the code from start as if the MCU was reset. The exact behaviour can be seen by looking at the MCU startup code, linker map file, code outpt listing, or disassembled binary.

So it's the main program that will be periodically run, and there is likely nothing wrong with your PWM duty setting code.

Move the return out of the main loop, it does not belong there, but outside it.

Comment: `the return statement is inside the infinite while loop` @InBedded this would not have happened as easily with properly formatted program code.

Comment: @greybeard assuming that you meant to tag me... why are you tagging me? I know that.

Comment: @greybeard well then you probably should have tagged SkePsis haha. I'm not OP

Answer (score 2):

You really need to separate out the button press from the PWM settings as you debug this.

Make sure your PWM settings are correct by making code that ONLY sets the PWM once, and verify that it works.  Next, change the PWM parameters, and try again.

Then start testing your button presses, maybe by setting a digital bit high or toggling it on a button press (and make sure switch bounce isn't killing you.

Once you've got both working robustly, try to put it together.

Apologies if you've already done this, but I suspect you haven't or your system would be working (or at the very least, your question would have been more specific).